# Is ${\rm rank} ( A^{{-1}/{2}} B A^{{-1}/{2}} )= 1$, if $A$ is symmetric (positive definite) and full-rank, and ${\rm rank} (B) = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is ${\rm rank} \left( A^{{-1}/{2}} B A^{{-1}/{2}} \right) = 1$, if $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is symmetric (positive definite) and full-rank, but ${\rm rank} (B) = 1 \in M_n(F)$?

Numerically, it seems to be true. But, I don't know yet how to prove it analytically.

I am sorry if this question is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem: if $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices of full-rank and rank one respectively then $ABA$ is of rank one.

Proof: since $B$ is rank one it can be expressed as $$B=uv^T$$where $u$ and $v$ are two non-zero n-tuple vectors. Therefore $$ABA=Auv^TA=(Au)(A^Tv)^T$$where $Au$ and $A^Tv$ are both two other vectors and therefore their multiplication is another rank one matrix. So $ABA$ is rank one and our proof is complete. You can replace $A$ with $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ in your own question.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying by the left or right by an invertible matrix does not change the rank (or nullity).

In this case it is easy to check, $BA^{-1/2}$ has rank at most one, because the rank is the dimension of its image equals the image of $B$, because $A^{-1/2}$ is invertible and hence its image is the whole space. We see that the image of $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ is at most one dimension. However it does not have rank zero since then it would be zero, but $A^{1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})A^{1/2} = B \neq 0$. So, it must be rank $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I like the answer. So, +1. But I was seeking a bit more rigorous proof.

Comment: Thanks, but in what way is it not rigorous, in your view?

Comment: As I said that, I indeed like your answer. Moreover, you have given a very good geometrical view. So, I have to merge both of your proofs. If I had the possibility to accept both, then I would have done that. I hope you understand me. I sincerely appreciate your answer and efforts.

Comment: Ok. I just interpreted 'not rigorous enough' as derogatory, because the proof is rigorous.

Comment: I apologize if I sounded that way. So, I take back my words because I didn't mean that way.

Comment: Ok. Have a nice time with your studies.